# array value not being properly emptied on a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

The goal I am trying to achieved is that when one of the two buttons(btn 1 or btn 2) are clicked the array needs to reset(emptied) and when button add is clicked value 1 needs to be pushed to the array. Here is what I came up so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var array = []
   $("#btn_1").click(function(){
       array = []
       add_to_array(array);
   })
   $("#btn_2").click(function(){
       array = []
       add_to_array(array);
   })   
})

function add_to_array(array){
  
    $("#add").click(function(){
    
     array.push(1)
     alert(array)
   })   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn_1">
empty array: btn 1
</button>

<button id="btn_2">
empty array: btn 2
</button>

<button id="add">
Add 
</button>
```

The problem I am facing: when I click either btn 1 or btn 2 more than once followed by add button, alert shows up the number of times I clicked btn1 or btn 2.

What I am looking for instead is, no matter how many times I click either btn 1 or btn2 I want alert two show up only once. Do you think what I am trying to achieve is achievable?

Comment: When do you want the alert to show up? Is there any specific condition?

Comment: When btn1 is clicked, there's an array that gets emptied, after that, btn1 is useless. When btn2 is clicked, is it the same array that btn1 emptied or does btn2 empty a different array? No matter if it's a different array or not, btn2 is now useless. Am I right so far?

Comment: why do you need add_to_array(). Why dont you add the code just inside the document.ready?

Comment: @selvassn the project I am working is a bit complicated than the above syntax. The best way to describe my challenge without revealing the whole project is as shown above.

Comment: @AvaLucas : Checkout my answer

Comment: @zer00ne For both buttons, I am using the same array. Both buttons are important even after they are clicked. I need to be able to click them as many times as I want and still get only one alert

Comment: Do you mean one alert but continue to add 1 for each proceeding click?

Comment: @Zer00ne I am looking for continues alert so that I can see the current array values.

Comment: When you call add_to_array inside the 2 buttons click handlers you're creating some kind of **closure** listening for the click event on the add button to get executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.off('click')` function to bind your event only once to add button.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var array = []
   $("#btn_1").click(function(){
       array = []
       add_to_array(array);
   })
   $("#btn_2").click(function(){
       array = []
       add_to_array(array);
   })   
})

function add_to_array(array){
  
    $("#add").off('click').click(function(){    
     array.push(1)
     alert(array)
   })   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn_1">
empty array: btn 1
</button>

<button id="btn_2">
empty array: btn 2
</button>

<button id="add">
Add 
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need, i have just modified your code in jquery, Whenever the empty button click, it empties the array, only when add button is pressed it adds 1 to array and alerts.

```js
array = [];
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#btn_1").click(function(){ 
        array = []
      }) 
    $("#btn_2").click(function(){ 
        array = []
      })
    $("#add").click(function(){ 
        array.push(1) 
        alert(array) 
      })
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn_1">
empty array: btn 1
</button>

<button id="btn_2">
empty array: btn 2
</button>

<button id="add">
Add 
</button>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Good Solution !! :)

Comment: unfortunately this does not work for me since I want to keep the function add_to_array.

Answer (score 0):

Make following changes , your onclick function should not be inside another function.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var array = []
   $("#btn_1").click(function(){
       array = []
       //add_to_array(array);
       alert('Array emptied')
   })
   $("#btn_2").click(function(){
       array = [];
       alert('Array emptied')
       //add_to_array(array);
   })   


function add_to_array(array){
  
   
    
     array.push(1)
     alert(array)
   
}


 $("#add").click(function(){
    
      add_to_array(array);
   })   

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn_1">
empty array: btn 1
</button>

<button id="btn_2">
empty array: btn 2
</button>

<button id="add">
Add 
</button>
```

Comment: I prefer value 1 to be added to the array only when button add is clicked instead of the other two buttons

Comment: @AvaLucas : then dont call the function on click ..check my edit above

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   var array = []
   $("#btn_1").click(function(){
       array = [];
       add_to_array(array)
   })
   $("#btn_2").click(function(){
       array = [];
       add_to_array(array)
   })
  $("#add").click(function(){
     array = [];
     array.push(1);
     alert(array);
   })   
})

function add_to_array(array){
     array.push(1);
}
</script>
<body>
<button id="btn_1">
empty array: btn 1
</button>

<button id="btn_2">
empty array: btn 2
</button>

<button id="add">
Add 
</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: unfortunately this does not work for me since I want to keep the function add_to_array

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I am facing: when I click either btn 1 or btn 2 more than once followed by add button, alert shows up the number of times I clicked btn1 or btn 2.

You call your function add_to_array() every time you click on `.btn_1` or `.btn_2` and it defines a new event listener on `#add` each time.
Plus you push 1 into your array in the same function. 
The click event should call your function, not the other way around.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var array = [];
   $("#btn_1").click(function(){
       empty_array(array);
   });
   $("#btn_2").click(function(){
       empty_array(array);
   });
   $("#add").click(function(){
       add_to_array(array);
       alert(array);
   })   
});

function empty_array(array) {
    array = [];
}

function add_to_array(array){
    array.push(1);
}
```

Comment: I prefer value 1 to be added to the array only when button add is clicked instead of the other two buttons

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment. 1 is added only when you click on #add

Answer (score -1):

Arrays can be emptied in multiple ways:

```
var arr =[];
arr.push(1);
//to empty an array
console.log(arr[0]);
arr.length=0;
console.log(arr);
```

Output would be:

> 1 []